# Error establishing mqtt connection over port 8883

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am building an C# application for publishing data over MQTT. The user should be allowed to choose if he wants to use SSL or not. MQTT connection over 1883 works fine. But I'm facing issues trying to achieve over port 8883. I'm confused with the MqttClient class overload methods. I followed this [link](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-m2mqtt).

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("broker.hivemq.com",
              MqttSettings.MQTT_BROKER_DEFAULT_SSL_PORT,
              true,
              new X509Certificate(Resources.m2mqtt_ca));
```

But when I tried to implement the same I got a build error saying

```
Error   1   'uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments.
```

So I decided to keep the next field same as my ca certificate and choose a random version for SSL. Below is my client side code.

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    client = new MqttClient(ddlServerIP.Text,
                 MqttSettings.MQTT_BROKER_DEFAULT_SSL_PORT,
                 true, 
                 new X509Certificate("C:/openSSLcertificate/m2mqtt_ca.crt",new X509Certificate("C:/openSSLcertificate/m2mqtt_ca.crt"),
                 MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_0);  
    String clientId= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    byte code = client.Connect(clientId);
    switch (code)
    {
      case 0:
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Accepted with return code " + code);
        Simulation frmSim = new Simulation();
        frmSim.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Simulation_FormClosed);
        frmSim.Show();
        BEConnect frmBeConnect = new BEConnect();
        FormProvider.MainMenu.Hide();
        break;

      case 1:
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Refused with return code " + code + Environment.NewLine + " unacceptable protocol version");
        break;
      case 2:
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Refused with return code " + code + Environment.NewLine + " identifier rejected");
        break;
      case 3:
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Refused with return code " + code + Environment.NewLine + " Server unavailable");
        break;
      case 4:
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Refused with return code " + code + Environment.NewLine + " bad user name or password");
        break;
      case 5: 
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Refused with return code " + code + Environment.NewLine + " not authorized");
        break;
      default:
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
        break;
      }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

  }
```

I also made the following changes on my mosquitto.conf file which runs on a Raspberry Pi which is my server side. Still I end up getting an exception connecting to the broker.

```
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

port 1883

listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/m2mqtt_ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/m2mqtt_srv.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/m2mqtt_srv.key
require_certificate false
```

Mosquitto log is as below:

```
1510146433: New connection from 192.168.0.9 on port 8883. 
1510146433: OpenSSL Error: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher 
1510146433: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting
```

Comment: You've not said what error you get with the 2nd bit code you've posted. Also have you tried testing connecting to port 8886 on the broker with a known client (e.g. mosquitto_sub)?

Comment: OK, so what happens if you use TLS 1.2?

Comment: @hardillb I get an exception which simply says "exception connecting to broker "